# Trying to destroy my player using Vector3.distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to destroy my player whenever the explosion particle effect comes within a certain distance of the player. Here is what I tried and this script was added to my explosion prefab:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExplosionController : MonoBehaviour {


GameObject playerObj;
Transform player;
Transform playerPos;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {


    player= GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    playerObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");


}
void Update()
{
    float playerDis = Vector3.Distance(player.position, transform.position);

    if (playerDis == 4)
    {
        Debug.Log(playerDis);
        Destroy(playerObj);
    }

}

}
```

My Debug attempt at the bottom condition didn't yield any console output, so I assume I made a mistake in the `playerDis` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment because I don't have 50 reputation points yet, but I would change your

```
if (playerDis == 4)
```

to

```
if (playerDis <= 4)
```

This should catch any collisions that may not exactly equal 4.00.... because Update may not be called fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

With the keyword in your question being 'within'.. You should look for a distance from 0 to 4. So:

```
void Update()
{
    float playerDis = Vector3.Distance(player.position, transform.position);

    if (playerDis <= 4)
    {
        Debug.Log(playerDis);
        Destroy(playerObj);
    }

}
```

I assume that your distance is never exactly equal to 4, considering that Vector3.Distance() returns a float.